# How to get returned sObject values In LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, js

I'm very new to LWC, can someone help me with how do I get returned sObject field values in LWC.
JS:

```
handleQuoteChange(event) {
        this.quoteRecordId = event.target.options.find(opt => opt.value === event.detail.value).value;
        
        getQuotationFields({quoteId : this.quoteRecordId}).then(result =>{
            
            this.quotation = result;
            
            console.log("Names Field:"+this.quotation.Name);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("Error:"+error.body.message);
        });
        
    }
```

Apex Method:

```
public class ComboboxLWC {
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Quotation__c getQuotationFields(Id quoteId){
        Quotation__c objQuote = [SELECT ID,Name,Unit__c,Project__c,Total_Agreement_Amount__c,GST__c,CGST__c,SGST__c,Total_with_Tax__c,Furnished__c,Furnishing_Rate__c FROM Quotation__c WHERE ID =:quoteId ];
        
        return objQuote;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that you are returning some data based on a ID(quoteRecordId) that an user has passed from the component. Your output data is stored in (quotation). Now what problem are you exactly facing? Showing it in the component or something like that? Can you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: @Night  I just want quotation Name field in js function. In colsole.log() it's showing error because this.quotation.Name is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'result' returns the list of records that you fetched. When you save it in 'quotation' you cannot just write `console.log("Names Field:"+this.quotation.Name);` to see the values. You need to iterate as shown below to see the results:

```
for(let i=0; i<this.quotation.length; i++){
                console.log(this.quotation[i].Name); }
```

Comment: Thanks for informing me about the return type of result, I have to change my Apex method return type to List<Quotation__c> and then I can Iterate over result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `result` which may cause the issue, result is a combination of data and error.

try this:

```
this.quotation = result?.data;
```

if `result.data` is an array then you can try:

```
this.quotation = result?.data[0];
```